# Prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

> Prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$

**Attempt:**

We must show that for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta > 0$, such that if $|x-a|<\delta$ and $|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}|<\epsilon$ for all $a \in (\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.

$\quad$**Scratchwork for $\delta$:**.

$\begin{align}
\quad \quad |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}|=|\frac{a-x}{xa}|&=\fbox{$\frac{1}{|xa|}$}|x-a|\\&=4|x-a|<\epsilon \\ &\Rightarrow|x-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{4} 
\end{align}$

$\quad \quad $ **In order to bound $\frac{1}{|xa|}$ (or $\frac{1}{xa}$; since $a,x>0$), I used the fact that $x,a>\frac{1}{2}$.

$\quad \quad $Which would result in $\frac{1}{|xa|}=\frac{1}{xa}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}}=4$.

$\quad$**Choose** $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{4}\\$

$\quad$**Proof:**.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. If $|x-a|<\delta$ we have:

$\begin{align}
\quad \quad |\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}|&=\frac{1}{|xa|}|x-a|\\&\leq4|x-a|\\ &<4\delta=4\frac{\epsilon}{4}=\epsilon. 
\end{align}$

$\rule{18cm}{.03cm}$

Is it enough to use the fact that that $x,a>\frac{1}{2}$, in order to place bounds on the function in order to reach a $\delta$? Any guidance or advice to strengthen the integrity of this proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is correct for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, here is a much faster way to prove this result. Indeed, $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ and one has, over $\left(\frac{1}{2},+\infty \right)$, $$|f'(x)|=\left| \frac{1}{x^2}\right| \leq 4$$

so $f$ is $4-$lipschitz, so $f$ is uniformly continuous over $\left(\frac{1}{2},+\infty \right)$.